# 1D xarray with secondary indices

Tags: python-xarray

I'd like to have a 1D array with a "primary" index and then add other indices to the same axis. For example, if my data looks like this,

```
[(a1, b1), (a2, b2), ..., (an, bn)]
```

I could index the first value in the tuples by index. How can I do this in `xarray`?

Comment: Did you try to use the python dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xarray terminology for this is "[multidimensional coordinates](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/multidimensional-coords.html)". Example:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random(4)
z = np.arange(4)
x = np.arange(2, 9, 2)
y = np.arange(4) + 100
coords = dict(z=z, x=('z', x), y=('z', y))

arr = xr.DataArray(data, dims=["z"], coords=coords)
```

And `arr` is

```py
<xarray.DataArray (z: 4)>
array([0.665017, 0.136371, 0.547075, 0.586285])
Coordinates:
  * z        (z) int64 0 1 2 3
    x        (z) int64 2 4 6 8
    y        (z) int64 100 101 102 103
```

Then you can do nice stuff like

```py
>>> arr.where(arr.y > 100)
<xarray.DataArray (z: 4)>
array([     nan, 0.136371, 0.547075, 0.586285])
Coordinates:
  * z        (z) int64 0 1 2 3
    x        (z) int64 2 4 6 8
    y        (z) int64 100 101 102 103
```

but we're still dealing with a 1-dimensional object:

```py
arr.shape  # (4,)
arr.dims   # ('z',)
```